# Don't see Entity Framework Template after Visual Studio 2010 install on Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I just install Visual Studio 2010 on a 64 bit VM with Windows 7 64 bit.  The VM is on an ESXi Hypervisor.  When I tried to create my first project I don't see the Entity Framework template (ADO .NET Entity Framework).  Am I missing a step here?  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

@Will thanks for all the help.  I was able to solve this problem by using the following steps:

1. Reinstall Visual Studio 2010 Professional
   a. Select Add New Components
   b. Click until you get to the comnponents selection screen
   c. de-select and re-select Visual Basic .NET and C#
   d. Click Update
2. Log back into Visual Studio 2010 Professional and you will have access to the ADO .NET Entity Framework

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 3):

I just had the very same problem. Actually, you have to check "SQL Server 2008 express" in Visual Studio installation, or Entity Framework won't be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're targeting 4.0 and not 3.5.

Comment: Yes I am targeting 4.0 for the project and yes I did start a project.  A MVC Solution with a class library as my DAL.  I want to add the entity framework to my DAL class.

Comment: @Brono that was how I screwed up the first time...  I seem to remember something about 4.0/4.0 client as well, so try switching from one to the other and see if that works.  Also, use the search box and type "Entity" to make sure you're not missing it.

Comment: @Will, per your suggestion i tried switching between 4.0 and 4.0 client but did not work...tried search but nothing found...I do see LINQ to SQL...even tried reinstall...maybe i need to uninstall everything and start over from scratch..bummer

Comment: @Brono no idea.  Check in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data\1033 for the file AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip.  If its not there there's something wrong with your install... unless you're running Express and its not included?  Not sure about that.  In that case you'd have to see if the EF4 designer is included in the Express version.

Comment: @Will I checked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates but did not see a folder for CSharp...how do i get that folder and it's sub folders?  Plus the corresponding one for VB?

Comment: @Will...just checked on the internet and looks like my problem is due to the fact that i don't have "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools" installed...when i get home tonight i will reinstall and make sure to check the boxes for vb and c#...hopefully that will solve my problem....we will see

Comment: @Brono, ugh, are you using Beta 2 or the RC rather than the RTM?  Because those do require a separate download.

Comment: @Will I have a MSDN Professional Subscription and got it off the site.  It says Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.  It is Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional...maybe i should ping microsoft support on this one...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you have to start a project (web application, wpf application etc), and then add ado.net entity data model.

See fourth figure on this page:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx

Update

Try

devenv /installvstemplates