# Missing ADO.net Entity framework template in VS 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, templates, ado.net

I am having VS 2010 Professional with SP1. I can see EF listed under Uninsall/remove a program list.

I have already referred these questions which don't have any solution. Hence starting a new thread.

- [SO entry1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entity)
- [SO entry2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846048/dont-see-entity-framework-template-after-visual-studio-2010-install-on-windows-7)

Searching over internet didn't provide much help either. There were few blogs suggesting to reinstall VS 2010.

Is there a way I can download and copy ADO.net EF template on my machine without the need to reinstall VS 2010. Thank you.

**Screen capture from Unistall/remove programs**

[image: Screen capture from Unistall/remove programs]

**Missing Template in VS 2010 SP1**

[image: Missing Template in VS 2010 SP1]

**.net Target Framework**

[image]

**Missing template (.zip)**

[image]

Comment: Interesting. What version of .NET framework is your project configured for?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, I have set the target framework to .net 4. Please refer the edited question with screen capture. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entity/6930728#6930728 it seems it is given as "Add new item" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling VS 2010 fixed the problem with ADO.net EF project template.

1. Uninstall VS 2010
2. Uninstall all Add-ons like SL toolkit EF Library 4.0
3. Install VS 2010
4. Install any other add-ons

Restart the machine when requested by the installer.

---

Also, please try out this.

When I ran VS 2010 in maintenance mode, the EF template problem got fixed. But I was not able to create any EDMX. I got missing DLL error. 
I did not try copying DLL from other's machine. I think that might have fixed the problem.

---

[**Edit**]

### As Sutikshan Dubey has suggested, please check if "Add New item" fixes the problem [No Entity Data Model (EDMX) Template with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 & ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entit)

Answer (score 5):

The template itself is normally located under *\Program Files[ (x86)]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\ide\itemtemplates\CSharp\Data\1033* in a zipfile called AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip . There is also a copy in *\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ **ItemTemplatesCache**\CSharp\Data\1033* , which is where VS reads it from.

Does that file exist in both locations? If not, copy it from another machine. If it exists but doesn't show up in VS, something else is wrong. In that case try running devenv.exe once with the /resetskippkgs command line parameter.

Comment: Thanks (+1). The template AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip  is not available on my machine. Is this zip file available on internet that I can download?

Comment: I don't think it is available for download, but if you have VS2010 installed on another system you can just copy it across.

Comment: I copied the zip file from a different machine and relaunched VS with /resetskippkgs option. Yet, the template doesn't show up. FYI, I downloaded source code from http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx and it is building and executing without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on VS2010 SP1, with Win7 and SQL Server 2008. Did not want the hassle of uninstall/reinstall VS2010 so kept looking. Found this solution here that got the template to work:
[No Entity Data Model (EDMX) Template with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 & ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entity)

I still get some error messages at load time of VS2010, but have not yet tried the /resetskippkgs switch after installing the EF.